# can bootstrap tabs show code?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use the bootstrap panels and tabs to show an image and then on the tab to show code. How Can I do this? I am writing in haml. What is the proper way to use the pre and code tags? When I do this the code in the HTML executes the form, but all i want to show is the code i use on how to do it.

thanks

[image]

```
    .col-md-4
      .panel.panel-default
        .panel-body
          .container
            %ul.nav.nav-tabs
              %li.active
                %a{:href => "#home"} Preview
              %li
                %a{:href => "#menu1"} HTML
              %li
                %a{:href => "#menu2"} HAML
            .tab-content
              #home.tab-pane.fade.in.active
                .col-md-3
                  %img{:alt => "Forms", :src => image_path('form.png'), :style => 'width: 100%; height: auto;'}  
              #menu1.tab-pane.fade
                %h3 HTML
                %pre
                  %code
                    %p
                      <div class="section section-form">
                      <div class="section-head">Form</div>
                      <div class="section-body">
                      <form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" disabled>
                      </div>
```

Comment: can you explain with a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it

```
               %pre
                  %code
                    :ruby
                      html = <<-HTML
                        <div class="section section-form">
                        <div class="section-head">Form</div>
                        <div class="section-body">
                        <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" disabled>
                        </div>
                      HTML
                    = html
```